# Searching SQL for specific CHAR

Tags: sql, command

I have a database table were a column holds multiple strings. They are holding License Plate numbers. If I search for 1 il get the first registration it finds with a one. I want to set it so that I must enter the full string and if I don't it should say not found. Here is my code. I'm sure its just the SQL command that needs altering for this.

```
public Car getCar(String searchLicense) {
    Car foundCar = new Car();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement
                .executeQuery("select * from eflow.registration where cLicense like '%" + searchLicense + "%'");

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            foundCar = new Car(resultSet.getInt("cID"), resultSet.getString("cLicense"),
                    resultSet.getInt("cJourneys"), resultSet.getString("cUsername"),
                    resultSet.getString("cPassword").toString());
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return foundCar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the exact string, you will need to remove the '%' in the LIKE filter.
Your code should be:

```
cLicense like '" + searchLicense + "'
```

The '%' wildcard put before and after the parameter you have, enables you to search for any string containing the searchLicense value in the middle, without checks of what is before or after that string.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using parameterized queries. [Bobby Tables: A guide to preventing SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Then use `=` instead of `like`.

```
select * from eflow.registration where cLicense = @searchLicense
```